# How can I pass navigator props to HOC?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I want to pass parameters to hoc. I saw that react-navigation method withNavigation. Is there available like this method on react-native-navigation? Or how can I do this method?

Comment: Can you provide example about this parameters you want to pass in? and what have you tried

Comment: I want to use push, setStyle etc. do you know withNavigation methods on react-navigation ?